# Odoo DIN5008 append or change information_block via XPATH

Tags: xpath, odoo, qweb, odoo-15

I'm in a similar situation like:

[Odoo DIN5008 append or change information_block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73302777/odoo-din5008-append-or-change-information-block)

I'd like to add some fields (e.g. the customer number) to the DIN5008 `information_block` in quotation and invoice PDF reports, but I'd like to do it via QWeb inheritance only, i.e. without patching the python code. However, I cannot seem to get to the `information_block` via XPATH at all, neither via `<xpath expr="//t[@t-foreach='template_data']" position="after">` (as taken from the source template) nor via `<xpath expr="//div[@class='information_block'] position=after>` (as taken from the code that's been rendered to the client).

I assume this is due to the template being a different file than what I can reach via inheriting from `report_saleorder_document`.

I can't figure out how to inherit from `external_layout_din5008`, and even if I figured that out, how would I differentiate the document type that's currently rendered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `inherit_id` template attribute, used to alter existing templates in-place.

***Example:***

```
<template id="external_layout_din5008" inherit_id="l10n_de.external_layout_din5008">
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-foreach='template_data']" position="after">
        <tr><td>Mobile:</td><td><t t-esc="o.partner_id.mobile"/></td></tr>
    </xpath>
</template>
```

You can use `o._name` to get the model name (`purchase.order` in the following example) but it it better to customize the information block for each document by defining the following three fields in the model: `l10n_de_template_data`, `l10n_de_document_title` and `l10n_de_addresses`

***Example:***

```py
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order'

    l10n_de_template_data = fields.Binary(compute='_compute_l10n_de_template_data')
    l10n_de_document_title = fields.Char(compute='_compute_l10n_de_document_title')
    l10n_de_addresses = fields.Binary(compute='_compute_l10n_de_addresses')

    def _compute_l10n_de_template_data(self):
        for record in self:
            record.l10n_de_template_data = data = []
            if record.state == 'draft':
                data.append((_("Request for Quotation No."), record.name))
            elif record.state in ['sent', 'to approve', 'purchase', 'done']:
                data.append((_("Purchase Order No."), record.name))
            elif record.state == 'cancel':
                data.append((_("Cancelled Purchase Order No."), record.name))

            if record.user_id:
                data.append((_("Purchase Representative"), record.user_id.name))
            if record.partner_ref:
                data.append((_("Order Reference"), record.partner_ref))
            if record.date_order:
                data.append((_("Order Date"), format_date(self.env, record.date_order)))
            if record.incoterm_id:
                data.append((_("Incoterm"), record.incoterm_id.code))



    def _compute_l10n_de_document_title(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.state in ['draft', 'sent', 'to approve']:
                record.l10n_de_document_title = _("Request for Quotation")
            elif record.state in ['purchase', 'done']:
                record.l10n_de_document_title = _("Purchase Order")
            elif record.state == 'cancel':
                record.l10n_de_document_title = _("Cancelled Purchase Order")

    def _compute_l10n_de_addresses(self):
        for record in self:
            record.l10n_de_addresses = data = []
            if record.dest_address_id:
                data.append((_("Shipping Address:"), record.dest_address_id))
            elif 'picking_type_id' in record._fields and record.picking_type_id.warehouse_id:
                data.append((_("Shipping Address:"), record.picking_type_id.warehouse_id.partner_id))
```

Example taken from [l10n_de_purchase](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/15.0/addons/l10n_de_purchase/models/purchase.py)

***Update:***

The information bloc values come from the `l10n_de_template_data` field and in the compute method you can see that it just appends a tuple holding the field label and value to a list so you can use the `t-esc` directive to append new values to `l10n_de_template_data` field before calling the external layout.

***Example:***

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<data inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">   
    <xpath expr="//th[@name='th_taxes']" position="replace" />
    <xpath expr="//td[@name='td_taxes']" position="replace" />
    
    <xpath expr="//t[@t-call='web.external_layout']" position="before">
      <t t-esc="doc.l10n_de_template_data.append(('Mobile', doc.partner_id.mobile))"/>
    </xpath>
    
</data>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. I'm using an inherited QWeb view to change the original `report_saleorder_document`, i.e. in the UI, not via a custom module, like so: ```<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data inherit_id="sale.report_saleorder_document">
  <xpath expr="//th[@name='th_taxes']" position="replace" />
  <xpath expr="//td[@name='td_taxes']" position="replace" />
</data>``` to remove the tax column. I also want to use this same inherited view to add to the `information_block`, just for sales orders

Comment: You can add data to the `l10n_de_template_data`  field, Check my edit.